# ABAP cdhdr-cdpos find who is change tel number in crm

Tags: sap-crm

I have a problem. I want to find who has changed a tel number in SAP CRM and after show partner number in ISU system but I find cdhdr-objectid and it begins CAM1000. How to find partner number ? Which tables find to  partner number ?

Comment: In which object type do you find a changed tel number? Business partner?

Comment: @Gerd Castan  I found object types : BP and CAM How I solved it?